# R: Split large character lines into slices

Tags: r, split, character

For a large dataframe containing 99150000 rows, the following code splits the data `my_df` into chunks of 1000 rows and writes to the disk.

```
lapply(seq(1, nrow(my_df), by = 1000),
       function(i) write.table(my_df[i:i+1000-1,]
                               , file = paste0('path_to_logal_dir/data'
                                               , i, '-', i+1000-1, '.csv')
                               ,row.names = F,col.names = F,quote = F)
)
```

Now, I have the same data (99150000 elements) in the character format, sample data below:

```
[1] "1979_1,532,40,7.7,12.9,116.9,12.9,85,2,2.001,4,25,55,5.3,55,85,7.7,85,145,7.5,145,265,5.0"
[2] "1979_2,532,40,7.7,12.9,116.9,12.9,85,2,2.001,4,25,55,5.3,55,85,7.7,85,145,7.5"
[3] "1979_3,532,40,7.7,12.9,116.9,12.9,85,2,2.001,4,25,55,5.3,55,85,7.7,85"
...
[99150000] ...
```

How could I achieve the same task above, that is, splitting the character format data into chunks (files containing 1000 lines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution made using only base R. You can easily generalize it using apply family or purrr package. First I create some fake data

```r
fake_data <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
fake_data
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H"
```

You want to divide your character vector into groups of 1000 lines. For simplicity I divide this vector into groups of 2 lines

```r
group_length <- 2
```

This means that the first 2 elements of the character vector belong to the first group, the second 2 elements belong to the second group and so on

```r
groups <- rep(1 : (length(fake_data) / group_length), each = group_length)
groups
#> [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
```

Now I divide the character vector into subgroups based

```r
splitted_groups <- split(fake_data, groups)
splitted_groups
#> $`1`
#> [1] "A" "B"
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] "C" "D"
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] "E" "F"
#> 
#> $`4`
#> [1] "G" "H"
```

and create a for loop to save each subgroup to a file

```
for (i in seq_len(length(fake_data) / group_length)) {
  table_data <- data.frame(x = splitted_groups[[i]])
  write.csv(table_data, file = paste0("data", i, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You could also replace the last for loop using the map family defined in the purrr package.